# More clear "log in using google" dialog-option

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app

The first login option (which *I suppose* uses the Google account info stored by Android) got me confused.

I clicked on it and then... I kept waiting. I did not realize I have to tap on my Google account name to proceed:

[image]

It has been brought to my attention that it is possible to have more than one Google account on Android, and therefore when you tap the "Log in using Google" button, the application brings up a dialog with a list of the accounts (not an info dialog as I initially thought), letting you choose the account to use for login. It is good to have this implemented (more choice), but I feel it can be improved.

- I think the UI is misleading (I was fooled, after all... The button looks totally like a label, not a button. Am I getting to old to appreciate the difference?)
- Also, as 98.9% of Android users (I completely made this up, but should be close enough) have one google account, why do not log the user with that account, if it is the only one that can be chosen?

Comment: For the record: earlier today I submitted a bug report because I thought it was a malfunction. But other users pointed out how it works, and suggested I should delete the bug report and re-submit it as a feature request, if I cared.

Comment: What happened with your previous question?

Comment: @Paresh it was deleted by a mod.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd why so? And again allowed him to post brand new question ?

Comment: @PareshMayani I asked it to be deleted because the question was a mess, and not really a bug... It seemed the right think to do (the bug was my misunderstanding)

Comment: @Paresh what Lorenzo said. In short, he thought it's a bug. After he discovered it's not a bug he decided to ask for a change. Totally legit action.

Comment: Ohh One more question for the same issue/bug: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192272/log-in-using-another-openid-and-logout , @ShaWizDowArd don't you think he should have updated that question with proper detail?

Comment: @Paresh no that's a separate problem, he did embed this in the now deleted first bug report which only added to the mess. This app is still new, I think it's only natural to have influx of reports and requests. The more the better, if you ask me! :-)

Comment: @PareshMayani what  Sha Wiz Dow Ard said. I felt the question messy as I wrote it the first time, and even worse after the edit. I though it better to have two questions, one per-issue/request

Comment: Actually a lot of other apps use this method of authenticating and a lot of(can't say most as I don't have any stat) android users find it intuitive(at least I did, and anyone who faced the same earlier would do). If there is no other obvious way to modify the dialog, this might be of low priority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have made a slight improvement here.  If your device only has one account we will show it on the login screen and bypass the account selection.  If there are more than one we will continue to show the existing "Log In to Google as.." dialog.

This will be in v0.1.16

Comment: Thanks! I think this is the best option.

Answer (score 2):

I don't make such mistake as alert dialog is clearly having title **"Log In using Google as:"**.

And yes try to add 1 account in your android device and then test this case, it will show you options depicted in below:

[image]

As you are having more than 1 account, it will show you dialog box with all the added accounts. And dialog is clearly depicting that one has to select one email and then he/she can proceed further with selected account.

**What if device is having only 1 account:**

I am agree with your point, its misleading for the first time user especially when user is having single account added in device.

### Solutions:

1. **Shortcut solution:** Here programmer of the app to give some kind of background/padding or highlight in different color.
2. **Standard solution:** It *should show all the options (whether one or more than one) using Radio buttons* and there way it would be clearly depicting value selection, something like given below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for trying it with two accounts. I think that they still look a bit too much like labels, not buttons (background color as you suggested may help.. what is the standard Android guideline here?) but this is an Android design issue.. And if it has more choices like this it is clear you have to make a choice

Comment: @LorenzoDematté updated answer with standard solution.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't make this mistake, and I think more Android users than you guesstimated have more than one Google Account attached to their mobile.

Also I suspect a large number of users will know to click the email, even with just one account.

It would be nice to hear from others and see what the consensus is.

Comment: Sure, my quesstimation was clearly biased to show my point :)

Comment: I think I would look at it in a puzzled way and then click the email to see what happened.
So I would have got there, but it's hardly intuitive, I would think it was a bug when it loaded