# "Log in using another OpenId" and logout

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, android-app, openid

I started the Android app, and I went to the second login option ("Log in using another OpenId") and entered my google account credentials. Authorized the app, and got to the feed.

Then, I logged out.

I wanted to try to log-in again using another set of openid credentials (to show the app to my coworker). So I choose again "Log in using another OpenId" but... it automatically logged me in using the google account credentials I entered the first time.

I find this behavior.. strange! How can I login with another set of openid credentials? (without erasing the application data from the Android application settings?)

Comment: I think you need to log out from Gmail as well, though don't know if it's possible on android device

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I tried to rebbot, thinking that may clear the cookie/access token/whatever, but no luck

Comment: Nope, when site has "remember me" feature it's done with cookies or local storage, both are permanent.

Comment: I also tried to clear cookies in the browser, but I suppose they use a WebView and that stores cookies in the app data

Comment: Clearing the application data works. I suppose the best way to deal with it is to clear cookies when the user clicks on Log Out. It is a minor bug but..

Comment: You mean the application data of Stack Exchange app? Anyway better post this as an answer, sounds like it might be useful for others as well. :)

Comment: Yes. If you go to Setting-> Application manager and select the Stack Exchange app, then click on "Clear data", you can login with another set of credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed prior to version 1.0, it turns out the `WebView` we were using for OpenID login was by default using a `CookieStore` which didn't get cleared when you logged out.